# How to install unison-gtk in NixOS?

Tags: nixos, unison

The title pretty much says it.

I installed NixOS 20.03 in a virtual machine to play a little with it and, if all goes well, install it on my work laptop.

I use Unison's gui, `unison-gtk`, to keep the laptop and my main production machine in sync. I found the [unison package on the search page](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=20.03&query=unison), but this package does not install `unison-gtk`, and there seems to be no package for it either. How can I install it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the gui included with the `unison` package different to what `unison-gtk` would provide?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think it solves my problem. I had not thought about testing unison with the graphic interface because up until version 2.48.4, which I regularly use in Ubuntu, the unison package does not include a GUI. One needed a separate package for that. The `-ui` option in unison simply tells you that the package only offers a text-based interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NixOS, the `unison` package includes a GUI, no need for a separate package.